# Prove $|\sin z| \le e ^{|\Im z|}$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove $|\sin z| \le e ^{|\Im z|}$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$

I think it's an easy proof, but I am stuck with inequalities. I get
$$\frac12 |e^{ix-y} -e^{-ix+y}|$$

and I have to switch this inequality, but exponentials can never become $0$ obviously,
so it will always be less than $e^{|\Im z|}$, I am not sure how they have equality sign there.

Comment: Please refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax on this site.

Comment: $1 \le 2$ is a true statement. Besides: you have equality for $z = \pi/2$.

Comment: @AlexR No, of course not. Where did I claim that?

Comment: @AlexR The OP seemed confused by thinking he could prove the stronger statement: $|\sin z| < e^{|y|}$, and not seeing why  $\le$ is also true. ("I am not sure how they have equality sign there.") I just wanted to clear up the not-so-uncommon misunderstanding about the usage of $<$ and $\le$.

Comment: @mrf Thanks (+1ed the more elaborate version)

Comment: I mean its greater or equal to...it just seemed weird though. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put $\;z=x+iy\;$ :$$\left|\sin z\right|=\left|\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right|=\frac12\left|e^{-y+ix}-e^{y-ix}\right|\le$$

$$\le\frac12\left(|e^{-y+ix}|+|e^{y-ix}|\right)=\frac12\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right)\le\frac122\,e^{|y|}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$|e^{ix}| =1$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $|e^{z+w}| = |e^z| |e^w|$ for $z,w\in\mathbb C$ This implies
$$|e^z| = |e^{\Re z}| = e^{\Re z} \qquad \forall\ z\in\mathbb C$$
Use this with your expansion to conclude the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin z=\sin (x+iy)=\sin x \cos (iy) + \cos x \sin (iy)=\sin x \cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$$

then

$$|\sin z|^2=\sin^2 x \cosh^2 y+\cos^2 x\sinh^2 y\le$$

$$\le (\cos^2x+\sin^2 x)( \cosh^2 y+ \sinh^2 y)=\cosh(2y)\le e^{2|y|}$$